# Google AdWords API special values (< 10% or > 90%)

Tags: api, analytics, google-ads-api

Some of the fields of the performance reports return special values such as "< 10%" or "> 90%" instead of returning the actual percentage.  I was wondering if anyone knew a way to get an actual percentage value for these fields.  I am trying to chart the data over time and it doesn't help me much when it just says "< 10%".  I don't have any way to accurately chart that next to actual percentage values on the same axis.

Comment: Just wondering, have you found a way around this?

Comment: Nope. Looks like there is no way around it, you just have to deal with their crappy values.